# Vue & Laravel: Call a PHP from a Vue component?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-blade

I have a blade template (php file) and I'm fine with passing in some PHP data as props that I encoded to json but how about if I need to specifically call a PHP function?

**blade php file**

```
<Component1
   :customer-data={{ !! json_encode($customer->customerData) }}
>

</Component1>
```

Inside of my component, I am triggering a javascript function that starts the payment processor and the callback needs to trigger the PHP function which is `checkoutWithCard()`, which the blade file obviously can trigger but the component has no knowledge of it.

**inside Component1.vue**

```
initializeStripePayment: function() {
        var stripe = StripeCheckout.configure({
            key: ######,
            allowRememberMe: false,
            token: function(token) {
                checkoutWithCard(token.id);
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: You cannot call PHP functions in Javascript. You are probably going to need to make an XHR request (axios, $.ajax)  in order to do this

Comment: no problem! You should be able to find the resources you need with that in mind